# Row estimates always too low

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, execution-plan

I have a query which involves a full-text search like this:

```
SELECT TOP 30 PersonId,
              PersonParentId,
              PersonName,
              PersonPostCode
FROM dbo.People
WHERE PersonDeletionDate IS NULL
      AND PersonCustomerId = 24
      AND CONTAINS(ContactFullText, '"mr" AND "ch*"')
      AND PersonGroupId IN(197, 206, 186, 198)
ORDER BY PersonParentId,
         PersonName;
```

This generates two main plans, one is very fast in all cases, the other is very slow in most cases.

I have experimented with this query such that the FT search is not included and what I found is that the row estimates are always way lower than they should be.

If I run `update statistics...with fullscan` I still see extremely inaccurate row estimates from NC index seek operations in the execution plan.

When the row estimates are low enough, a loop join is selected, which is normally very slow (30+ seconds). Higher estimates seem to produce a good plan involving a merge join instead of a loop join.

Why is SQL Server still not estimating the rowcounts despite still having up to date statistics?

The plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkXtE0jzX

When I remove the `CONTAINS` part, thereby omitting the FullText search, the query is fast, but the row estimate for the index seek is still 1 estimated, 2195 actual.

On @Kin's advice, I used CONTAINSTABLE, which ran instantly and produced the following plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1hKainzQ
Interesting that there is no Full Text search operator.

Containstable requires `RANK` to produce the same result set in this case I've used `AND RANK > 0` in the `WHERE` to produce the results I want, which produces this plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1U7AA2zm

My only question now is about why row estimates are still inaccurate but I care less now that my FT queries seem significantly faster and more reliable. Very pleased! 
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1U7AA2zm

@EvanCarroll stats histogram here: https://pastebin.com/p7s0NvX5

Some follow up info - before/after execution plans for some typical FT search queries for the application being supported

A

1. Before: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJlAAAN7X (5 seconds)
2. After: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1ltkkSmm (<1
   second)

B

1. Before: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy-gxJBQm (40
   seconds)
2. After: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy2VxJrm7 (1
   second)

C

1. Before: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1z5e1rQ7 (2
   seconds)
2. After: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1oplkSQm (<1
   second)

D

1. Before: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1kHf1BQQ (2
   minutes 20 seconds)
2. After: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1D5z1SQm (11
   seconds)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(summarizing my comments and putting as answer)*

A query rewrite will solve the issue of getting low row estimates.  As Joe Chang explains in his blog post  [Query Optimizer Gone Wild - Full-Text](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/joe_chang/archive/2012/02/19/query-optimizer-gone-wild-full-text.aspx)

> CONTAINS is "a predicte used in a WHERE clause" per Microsoft documentation, while CONTAINSTABLE acts as a table.

You get a much [better plan (merge join)](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1U7AA2zm) using `CONTAINSTABLE` vs the actual plan using `contains` uses a [nested loop join with low row estimates](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkXtE0jzX).

You can [rewrite the query](https://gist.github.com/TheRockStarDBA/db081a15243d38ccf64a85d2de3aa091) as :

```
SELECT TOP 30 p.PersonId,
              p.PersonParentId,
              p.PersonName,
              p.PersonPostCode
FROM dbo.People p
left join containstable (ContactFullText, '"mr" AND "ch*"') cf on cf.[yourKey] = p.PersonId
WHERE p.PersonDeletionDate IS NULL
      AND p.PersonCustomerId = 24
      --AND CONTAINS(ContactFullText, '"mr" AND "ch*"')
      AND p.PersonGroupId IN(197, 206, 186, 198)
      AND [RANK] > 0
ORDER BY p.PersonParentId,
         p.PersonName;
```

Comment: fantastic, thank you for your help. I have rewritten two of our worst FT search queries using CONTAINSTABLE and have tested various permutations of parameters/values and have so far seen great performance. Currently this solution is being tested by our Test department so hopefully by next week I'll get confirmation that all is working well. I will update the question with some execution plans to illustrate some of the interesting ways this affects execution plans and provide a bit more depth to the effect of your solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Fulltext queries are partially recompiled based off of the text in the contains clause. (From experience) I'm going to venture a guess that SQL Server is expecting a low number of rows from the relational predicates, and is doing a for-each loop "seek" into the FTS engine.  The seeks can be performance killers.

If you want predictable performance, then you can split the query into two parts.

```
SELECT ... INTO #tmpResults FROM CONTAINSTABLE()...

SELECT ... FROM #tempResults INNER JOIN People ....
```

You're not supposed to have to do this, but it works.